# Jquery script not working to alter CSS on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added some custom elements to be included with my WooCommerce account page to be seen with the order history. Unfortunately the page is setup with tabs to only display the information pertaining to the active tab.

I'm not very familiar with jquery, but I thought it would be simple enough to use Jquery to hide the divs I added when the order history has a display of none.

**I added the following script to my theme's main.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var display = $('.my_account_orders');
    if(display.css("display") == "none") {
        $('.paging-nav').css("display","none");
    }
});
```

When the class .my_account_orders has a display of none it should change the div I added (.paging-nav) to have a display of none. But it just doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with this script or do I need to do something special to initiate it? Since it's in my theme's main.js file and I used `$(document).ready(function()` I figured it would just load with the page.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got an errant $ in your if statement, try `if(display.css("display") == "none") {`

Comment: you dont have var `$display`

Comment: Does the edit you just made give a hint about the issue? Compare `display` with `$display`.

Comment: I just read through and tried all the solutions and suggestions given, but unfortunately it's still not working. I have updated the script above to reflect what I have tried last. Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
var display = $('.my_account_orders');
```

Implement it into the if statement like this:

```
if($('.my_account_orders').css("display") == "none") {
```

Because originally it is trying to find a variable called $display, so it would return a syntax error of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an errant $ in your if statement.  This should work instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var display = $('.my_account_orders');
    if(display.css("display") == "none") {
        $('.paging-nav').css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Also keep in mind that your `var display` is only going to match the first element that has a class of `my_account_orders`, so if there are multiple elements with that class, and they don't all have the same display, you could get unexpected results.

Comment: I tried using this but it does not work. I checked in both firefox and chrome as well. the class .my_account_orders is only used once on this page.

Comment: @nickyb can you share the rendered markup you're working with in a jsfiddle?  It would help us reproduce the problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var display = $('.my_account_orders');
if(display.css("display") == "none") {
        $('.paging-nav').css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a very lame way to check for a `css` property such as display to determine if an element is `hidden` or not. With jquery, you can make use of [:hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector which determines whether an element is `hidden` and return a `bool` value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($('.my_account_orders').eq(0).is(":hidden")) // eq(0) is optional - it basically targets the 1st occurring element with class 'my_account_orders'
    {
        $('.paging-nav').css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/sgcrupm8/2/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not working either. Perhaps there's something preventing the state change? I'll keep looking around for a bit longer, but it may be just as easy to hide and make the element visible again with a click event for the tabs.

Comment: I guess at this point of time, you might have to post the html as well to understand the exact issue.